# Some Sentence and Comma

Tags: commas, modifiers, adverbials

> Whatever the degree of integration, teaching autistic children effectively will require more funding, to train both specialist and
>   mainstream teachers.

Why do we need comma after "funding" and before "to" here?
Your response will help me a lot in understanding the English better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the comma.  In fact, it's better to leave out a comma between a word (here, the gerund *funding*) and the complement it licenses (here, the infinitive object of the gerund).  Alas, understanding punctuation may not help you much with English grammar.  Punctuation is a matter of style, and its rules are governed by manuals of style, which not only differ among themselves, but which recognize the many exceptions to rules and the importance of the judgment of writers.